# Galleria Miniml Theme Display Thumbnails First

Tags: galleria

I have recently bought the http://galleria.aino.se/themes/miniml/ theme and I wanted to reverse the order the thumbnails and stage display. click on the toggle thumbnails, it's really toggling the stage.

So when the page loads, the thumbnails display first, and when you toggle the thumbnails your really toggling the stage.

Does anyone know if there is an option for this? Or do I have to hack the theme?
Sorry I know this is a vague question and I'm not looking for a scripted answer unless someone know's it.

The theme is minified so I can't really extract the function I need.

Thanks for the responses, I have a funny feeling it'll be a no though. Gotta try!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Galleria.ready(function() {
    this.$('thumbs').click();
});
```